# jQuery 'reverse callback' from ASP page

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp-classic, callback

OK, I have a need to send a large request to a server running ASP::PERL and to have the server post back progress to the calling page.  Basically -> tell server to upload a whole bunch of files in a file share, then update a div on the client as each file is checked for error/uploaded/success or fail.

Is there a way to put some callback function in the backend ASP page to call a clientside JavaScript function on the loaded page?  This has to work in a loop on the server, so basically a pingback from the server to the client as each file is uploaded until all files are checked/uploaded.

Comment: This is an interesting topic. Personally I would approach this by having the client poll the server, with the server periodically updating some status table (or whatever). But I'll see what others have to say.

Comment: Ooo ... I wonder if it'd work to have the initial "POST" target a hidden iframe, and then what the server would do would be to send back a series of "script" blocks. Each script block would be complete, and would include just a function call to something in the parent page that'd update status. Maybe the browser would parse and execute the script tags as it received them, even though the overall page wasn't yet complete.

Comment: @Pointy I think you may be right in saying the browser won't parse the data until the request/response cycle has completed.

Comment: kinda smelly pointy, and you know it deep down ;-) keeping a long running connection just for progress updates... a good idea?

Comment: No I don't think it's a good idea at all, but there are people running million dollar websites all over the Internet doing stuff that I don't think to be good ideas.

Comment: well, this is an intranet site that doesn't get a huge amount of traffic.  Currently the way it is working is I call an ASP page (via AJAX) with each file path which happens to be the id of a target div tag on the client.  all works fine until we get a directory with 50+ drawings in it (this is for a CAD drawing managment system).  50+ drawings kills the server.

Long story short - we could afford a little smelly code here to get a job done.  I think I will investigate Pointy's idea and see where it leads me.  I will continue to entertain other ideas to, maybe there is a better way.

Comment: @pointy: i knew you knew that but couldn't not say something...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might get some mileage from this [**post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2260926/mail-sending-program-request-timeout/2260960#2260960). topic is bulk email but the strategy will work for your requirement..

Comment: ok, my earlier thoughts and tests are a nogo, lemme try this one.  Thanks for the code Sky - I will be putting it to the test to see if it can solve my issue.  Of course now I need to write a web service in PERL - but thats another question.

Answer (score 2):

Like the comment above says, (I'm pretty sure) you have to do this with polling.

When you send the files to the server, use the [setTimeout()](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp) function to register a callback function.  This function will "poll" the server, asking for the status of the operation (how many files... what % complete).  If the operation isn't finished, just re-register the same function -- with setTimeout() again -- just before your function completes.

```
var callback = function() {
  // (1) Use ajax to get status from the server
  // (2) Update the progress div
  // (3) If complete, signal the user and hide the progress bar;  otherwise register callback() again
}

var submitFiles = function() {
  // Send files to server
  setTimeout(callback, 1000);
}
```

Comment: I don't think that polling will work for me unfortuneatly.  I list each file on the client page and the users want to know the status of EACH file, not just the status of the whole transaction.  But I can't send each file and handle traditionally because I will beat the server to death on a big directory full of drawings.  Tis a though nut to crack this one.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your help folks.  I figured out how to do what we needed.  What it boiled down to was that we wanted to sort of stall the calls per file so that we didn't overwhelm our backend server with a whole bunch of file upload calls.  So, we chose a recursoin strategy that basically makes an asynch call, then waits until a success callback and handles the result - then calls the method again.  Here is some code:

```
function doAjaxCall(targetCheckBox)
{
    if ((targetCheckBox) == 'undefined' || targetCheckBox == null)
    {
       targetCheckBox = $('#toprint input:checkbox[id*=ChkIn]:checked:first');

       if ($(targetCheckBox).length == 0)
       {
            alert('All Files Processed!');
            if (!CheckForm()){
                $('#checkinbtn').remove();
            } else 
            {
                $('#checkinbtn').removeAttr('disabled');
                $('#checkinbtn').val('Check In');
            }
            return;
       }
    }

    var res = $(targetCheckBox).val().split("/");
    var targetID = res[res.length-1];
    var test = document.getElementById('comment_'+targetID);
    var commentField = $(test);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "loadfiles.asp", 
        data: getPostString($(targetCheckBox).val()), 
        success: function(result) {
            if (result.indexOf('Error')> -1){
                commentField.attr('style', 'background-color:#FF6267');
            } else {
                commentField.attr('style', 'background-color:#88CC55');
            }
            commentField.empty();
            commentField.html(result);
            $(targetCheckBox).remove();
            doAjaxCall(null);  // recurse on success until we don't have any more files
        }
    });
    $("#fileCounter").remove();
}
```